# How to save transformed file into new excel file using Openpyxl Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have 3 excel files currently  in my working directory. All 3 files has name that ends with "_Updated.xlsx". I wanted to transform the files such that all empty rows in each of the files get deleted. I have created function for it, but the only issue is I cannot save all transformed file using below code. Not sure what is wrong ? The reason for creating new file is I would like to save my raw files.

**Python code**

```
import openpyxl
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook,Workbook
import glob
from pathlib import Path

Excel_file_path="/Excel"

for file in Path(Excel_file_path).glob('*_Updated.xlsx'):
    wb=load_workbook(file)
    wb_modified = False
    for sheet in wb.worksheets:
        max_row_in_sheet = sheet.max_row
        max_col_in_sheet = sheet.max_column
        
        sheet_modified = False
        if max_row_in_sheet > 1:
            first_nonempty_row = nonempty_row() # Function to find nonempty row
            sheet_modified = del_rows_before(first_nonempty_row) #Function to delete nonempty row
            
            wb_modified = wb_modified or sheet_modified
            if wb_modified:
                for workbook in workbooks:
                    for sheet in wb.worksheets:
                        new_wb = Workbook()
                        ws = new_wb.active
                        for row_data in sheet.iter_rows():
                            for row_cell in row_data:
                                ws[row_cell.coordinate].value = row_cell.value
                                new_wb.save("/Excel/"+sheet.title+"_Transformed.xlsx")
```

Comment: Looks strangely like #72524903 :-/

Answer (score 1):

In case, if any one is still looking for answer to my above question. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
import openpyxl
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import glob
from pathlib import Path

Excel_file_path="/Excel"

for file in Path(Excel_file_path).glob('*_Updated.xlsx'):
    wb=load_workbook(file)
    wb_modified = False
    for sheet in wb.worksheets:
        max_row_in_sheet = sheet.max_row
        max_col_in_sheet = sheet.max_column
        
        sheet_modified = False
        if max_row_in_sheet > 1:
            first_nonempty_row = get_first_nonempty_row() # Function to find nonempty row
            sheet_modified = del_rows_before(first_nonempty_row) #Function to delete nonempty roW
            file_name = os.path.basename(file)
    wb.save("Excel/"+file_name[:-5]+"_Transformed.xlsx")
wb.close()
```